# How can I test a resizable circle SVG element?

Tags: reactjs, testing, drag-and-drop, cypress, react-testing-library

Trying to figure out how to properly test a resizable `<circle>` svg element.
I am new to React Testing Library, so I'm unsure if this is possible with RTL (with the Mocha test framework) or if I should use Cypress.

Let's say I have a circle element:

`<circle data-testid='circle-element' cx="100" cy="100" r="50"/>`

NOTE: 0,0 origin is at the top left.

The center of the circle is located at x=100, y=100 with a radius of 50.

[image]

Located on the edge of the circle at x=150, y=100 is a `Draghandle` where a user can click and drag to resize the circle.

```
<DragHandle
  data-testid='circle-draghandle'
  x={handleX}
  y={handleY}
  dragMove={onHandleDrag}
/>
```

If a user clicks on the `Draghandle` at its original location of x=150, y=100 and drags to x=200, y=100, we expect the circle radius to now be 100.

NOTE: the center of the circle is unchanged; still at x=100, y=100.

[image]

How can I test this?

I did figure out how to test if the circle rendered properly using `React Testing Library` with given coordinates and radius:

```
it('should render a Circle with the coordinates provided', function () {
    render(<Circle mark={{ cx: 100, cy: 100, r: 50}} />)

    expect(screen.getByTestId('circle-element'))
      .to.have.attr('r')
      .to.equal('50')
  })
```

NOTE: `<Circle>` is our component where the actual `<circle>` svg element lives.

Any help with testing the resizing part what be amazing!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - finally have a solution using React Testing Library and `user-events@14`!

Hopefully this will help someone else.

`user-events` must be 14.0 or higher.

import userEvent in testing file:

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
```

The test:

```
describe('Circle tool', function () {
  let mark
  beforeEach(function () {
    mark = CircleMark.create({
      id: 'circle1',
      toolType: 'circle',
      x_center: 200,
      y_center: 200,
      r: 50
    })
  })

  it('should change the radius when drag handle is moved', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup()

    render(<Circle mark={mark} />)

    expect(mark.x_center).to.equal(200)
    expect(mark.y_center).to.equal(200)
    expect(mark.r).to.equal(50)

    // click on dragHandle
    // move dragHandle
    // release mouse button
    const circleDragHandle = screen.getByTestId('draghandle')
    await user.pointer([
      { keys: '[MouseLeft>]', target: circleDragHandle },
      { coords: { x: 300, y: 200 } },
      { keys: '[/MouseLeft]' }
    ])

    expect(mark.x_center).to.equal(200)
    expect(mark.y_center).to.equal(200)
    expect(mark.r).to.equal(100)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tests for dragging can be difficult to implement, if using Cypress I recommend adding [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) library.

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="circle-draghandle"]')
  .realClick()
  .realMouseMove(200, 100)  // drag 100 right
  .realMouseUp()

cy.getByTestId('circle-element')   // from cypress-testing-library add-on
  .should('have.attr', 'r', '50')
```

The result may be close but not exact (say 49), in which case the test log will tell you.

If so you can use a `closeTo` assertion

```
cy.getByTestId('circle-element')
  .should('have.attr', 'r')
  .and(radius => {
    expect(radius).to.be.closeTo(50, 1)
  })
```

**Note**

The above would only work if your graphic is `<svg>`, but it can't be used for `<canvas>`.

Comment: Hey @Fody, Thanks for the response. Do you know if this test is possible in React Testing Library? We don't have Cypress in our project so I'll have to chat with a couple other Devs to see if we want to add it. If I can properly test this out and all is good, I'll come back, upvote and accept your response as solved.

Comment: Haven't done a lot with React Testing Library, but there is a mouseMove event (searching the repo) so perhaps `fireEvent.mouseMove('[data-testid="circle-draghandle"]', {x:200, y:100})`. Without docs, you'll have to play with the coords as they could be `clientX` (absolute) or `deltaX` (relative).

Answer (score 0):

Try below library-free solution to drag and drop:

```
cy.get('[data-testid="circle-draghandle"]')
.trigger('mousedown', { //simulating hold click
    button: 0
}).wait(700)
.trigger('mousemove', { //simulating drag
    pageX: 200, 
    pageY: 100,
    force: true
}).wait(250)
.trigger('mouseup', {  //simulating drop
    force: true
});
```

Then you could use Fody's suggested closeTo solution to check the result